# Using upgreek letter bring error missing $

Tags: tikz-pgf, groupplots

I am trying to create a TikZ picture with a groupplot inside (using pgfplots). I need an upright mu in the y axis label for the units. I had no problem in my previous figures which do not use groupplots but in this particular case, it send an error

> Missing $ inserted. \nextgroupplot[height=1.11cm]

The code producing this error is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, plotmarks, pgfplots.groupplots, pgfplots.units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{upgreek} % For non-italic greek letters

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2, vertical sep= 0.62cm},
            width=8.5cm,
            scale only axis, % To ensure same size on all pictures axis
            restrict y to domain=-5:40]


        % Plot main figure (a)
        \nextgroupplot[height=5.48cm,
        every axis y label/.append style={at=(ticklabel cs:0.3)},
        ylabel = Vertical deflection z (\upmu)]

        \addplot coordinates {(0,30) (6,5)};

        % Plot zoom (b)
        \nextgroupplot[height=1.11cm]

        \addplot coordinates {(0,-0.2) (6,-0.1)};

        \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that the following code (identical except for the `\upmu` replaced by m) works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, plotmarks, pgfplots.groupplots, pgfplots.units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{upgreek} % For non-italic greek letters

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2, vertical sep= 0.62cm},
            width=8.5cm,
            scale only axis, % To ensure same size on all pictures axis
            restrict y to domain=-5:40]


        % Plot main figure (a)
        \nextgroupplot[height=5.48cm,
        every axis y label/.append style={at=(ticklabel cs:0.3)},
        ylabel = Vertical deflection z (m)]

        \addplot coordinates {(0,30) (6,5)};

        % Plot zoom (b)
        \nextgroupplot[height=1.11cm]

        \addplot coordinates {(0,-0.2) (6,-0.1)};

        \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and gives me the following result:

[image]

Could you help me understand where the problem comes from?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that `\upmu` (from the package `upgreek`) is designed for `math mode`, but you are using `text mode` in your image. Your line is supposed to be

```
    ylabel = Vertical deflection z ($\upmu$)]
```

to use `\upmu` in `math mode`. Here's the working MWE:

````
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, plotmarks, pgfplots.groupplots, pgfplots.units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{upgreek} % For non-italic greek letters

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2, vertical sep= 0.62cm},
            width=8.5cm,
            scale only axis, % To ensure same size on all pictures axis
            restrict y to domain=-5:40]


        % Plot main figure (a)
        \nextgroupplot[height=5.48cm,
        every axis y label/.append style={at=(ticklabel cs:0.3)},
        ylabel = Vertical deflection z ($\upmu$)]

        \addplot coordinates {(0,30) (6,5)};

        % Plot zoom (b)
        \nextgroupplot[height=1.11cm]

        \addplot coordinates {(0,-0.2) (6,-0.1)};

        \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}```
````

Comment: It works perfectly fine with your corrcetion, thank you. Thought now I am wondering why it was working without the math mode in my other figures.

Comment: Maybe you a) start a new question facing this; b) made some re-definitions between some floats; c) use another environment or a (self-defined) command which includes one (hopefully this doesn't cause your confusion because you either didn't use it or you're aware of your environments, to be fair enough)…?

Comment: Self-defined commands seem a bit complicated for me... I will keep your answer that works and leave the rest of my figures until I improve with TikZ. Thanks!